# Mongoose find field with any value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a find query like:

```
 person = await PersonSchema.find({
        givenName: (gn == 'none') ? {} : gn,
        lastName: (ln == 'none') ? {} : ln,
        placeOfBirth: (pob == 'none') ? {} : pob,
        dob: { $regex: (dob == 'none') ? {} : dob }
    });
```

basically, if any of these fields equal 'none' I want to get all value returned... basically removing it from the query... does anyone know how to do this?

Or even think of another way of approaching this problem?

Comment: It would be better to do a `none` check and add what is eligible to the query. IT will not impact the performance.

Comment: @Gibbs Hello thanks for the answer, not sure what you mean could you write this in code thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $and in case your two fields don't equal 'none'. Maybe Like this ;

```js
const filter = [{}] // if all field equal none, default $and
gn !== 'none' && filter.push({givenName: gn})
ln !== 'none' && filter.push({lastName: ln})
pob !== 'none' && filter.push({placeOfBirth: pob})
dob !== 'none' && filter.push({dob: dob})

person = await PersonSchema.find({$and : filter});
```